# Typescript: Are mapped list types possible? Or can I change the Parameters<Func> Types via mapping?

Tags: typescript

Can I change the type of the types within a Typescript array type?

Code example:

```
const func1 = (x1: string, x2: string) => '${x1} + ${x2}';
const func2 = (x1: number, x2: number) => x1 + x2;

// i need sth like this 
// type Mapper<Type> = Array<Array<Property> keyof Type>;
// so that i can do this
// Mapper<Parameters<Fn>>

function callFunction<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => string | number>(func: Fn, ...params: Parameters<Fn>) {
  // do sth, example:
  const inputs = params.map(item => item[0]);
  func(...inputs);
}

callFunction(func1, ['1'], ['1']);  // and then there should be no error here
callFunction(func2, [1], [1]);  // and no error here
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAjDAvDAFADxQLhmgCcBLMAcwBoYcAmQk8igSgwD4YByAEgG88AXxgBqGP3qCuAbgBQoSLETI6GbHkJgEAWwBGAU2I16mnQeJt0nPKNp05sgPSOYpGGH36AJkSgALGAAbUgBrfRh-UggYJxcoAE8AB3CAWQBDROTiAB4AFST9TkwAQWJiNPjs0vLKgAViECyEzjD4kDgYfOT2OWciEAi-NNg3YDSwGC8ByIhYmHTMw2zatPLtfShDCGyAMTB2dllZZWAoUnAYMcDAnaRT87Bdif0cTbAvaKwAOh-VighCON4gBtAC6lk4TEoMAAPu4zIZ2FgToQ9jQfl9Eqs0toATAVmsNlsnuw2HxZDAYH0pr4-DQXjjEoF9PgKZdwNBXGBEggoNFMFi1hAvtoMlhSJttBxXJLgQAGcFySknb4-cg8vksOSCI5XG53M7gZF3FA0YFcFBcUFmi1WrWUvrjHz%20fQTF3EcIQPwgBCBHwGdwDQwNYgwPyGfTyNLXW7IQ1gY0qM0oa0wYEp%201UlxOwMwYMgUPhj2yIA)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `Array<Array<Property> keyof Type>` - this is not valid Typescript syntax.

Comment: `{[K in keyof Parameters<Fn>]: [Parameters<Fn>[K]]}`?

Comment: ```callFunction(func1, 'aa', 'bb'); // Parameters<func1> = ['string', 'string']```
```callFunction(func2, 1, 2); // Parameters<func2> = ['number', 'number']```

Comment: `{[K in keyof Parameters<Fn>]: [Parameters<Fn>[K]]}`: that would make an object out of it. I want to keep it as an array.

Comment: `Array<Array<Property> keyof Type>` ist just pseudo code. You can look at the typescript playground. I would like to get rid of the errors but keep the type check on the last 2 lines.

Comment: `callFunction(func1, 'aa', 'bb'); // Parameters<func1> = ['string', 'string']` would work for typescript but I actually want an array as an input.

Comment: I would like to change the internal type of Paramaters<Fn>. So let's say Parameters<Fn> = ['string', 'number']. I want to turn that into [string[], number[]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Maybe I didn't ask my question right. If that was the case just let me know.

But this works:

```
const func1 = (x1: string, x2: string) => '${x1} + ${x2}';
const func2 = (x1: number, x2: number) => x1 + x2;
const func3 = (x1: string, x2: number) => x1 + x2;

type Mapper<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U[][] : never;

function callFunction<Fn extends (...args: any[]) => string | number>
  (func: Fn, ...params: Mapper<Parameters<Fn>>) 
{
  // do sth, example:
  const inputs = params.map(item => item[0]);
  func(...inputs);
}

callFunction(func1, ['1'], ['1']);  // no error here
callFunction(func2, [1], [1]);  // no error here
callFunction(func3, ['1'], ['1']);  // error here would be nice but it's fine like that
```

See: [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAjDAvDAFADxQLhmgCcBLMAcwBoYcAmQk8igSgwD4YByAEgG88AXxgBqGP3qCuAbgBQoSLETI6GbHkJgEAWwBGAU2I16mnQeJt0nPKNp05C6PCTAAzGtwEiUMpWMMYLT1DS2s0MXo5WSgATwAHfRgAWQBDOITiAB4AFU5MbJh9HCh9MAATCGxyOEMYAFUWAG0AXRgAfnqWlphNfQA3QyjlYChScBhgFIAbKYAxF1HwTNmwQuLSiuwAOh2U4goIQhSwGJbQ718KGAAfQLNDdixhwhWaHa24vZTtQ%20S0jMyAAUvtp9CViBBlmB2Ow2HxZDAYAB6JEwMogbwACxoRW%20cSm%20nwCIm4Cc5DiCCglUwn2I3wgW20aSwpBK2g4MFZ%20m0jQADM0WHJEcMsO9yZSIILZIJZPJpnMFmMwE8XCgaI0uCguM11ZrtYLESiYMcyjAoJjSmaLcREhBMSAEFNTQZAhjDMQQMQYNb9HKZvNkItlcM6OqUDqYI1wwbkaiTa7CsQPV6fX6FYGlSrkK5dVqIxq8zGje7Pd7DIkAO4Op0wF1gUjARK6SmcqBcSpwciJKakADWiXNKSgsiAA)